# MonoGame references an unsupported version of nunit.framework

Tags: c#, mono, nunit, assemblies

I'm developing a C# project in Xamarin that uses MonoGame. I'd like to start writing tests, but when I added the NUnit assembly, wrote a stub test, and tried to execute it I got the following exception:

```
UnsupportedFrameworkException: Skipped loading assembly monogame-monomac because it references an unsupported version of the nunit.framework, 3.2.0.0
```

I'm fairly new to mono, so any help in sorting this would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you executing your tests? i.e. VS Adapter, NUnit-console, Resharper?

Comment: I used the "Unit Testing" view in Xamarin

Comment: That was a good suggestions, but unfortunately after downgrading NUnit I get the same error with MonoGame, but with an earlier version. Interestingly I installed NUnit versions 3.0.1, but the error message claims the unsupported version in MonoGame is 3.0.5.

Comment: Sorry, I'd mis-read - didn't notice the NUnit reference is in MonoGame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Chris's suggestion, I investigated what version of NUnit works with MonoGame. [Apparently](https://github.com/espes/MonoGame-Tests/blob/master/MonoGame.Tests.XNA.csproj) MonoGame can be used with NUnit 2.5.10, so I downgraded NUnit to that version and everything ran smoothly.